# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined when pressing menu item that navigates to other page

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have some issues with my menu when I use it on a mobile phone.
On a desktop the menu functions well but when I use it on a mobile phone I can't navigate to another page, it only works when scrolling to an id on the same page.
When I press the menu item: Idalium dawn, I receive the error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined. I hope that someone is able to help me :)

HTML code of the menu:

```
<nav class="site-navigation position-relative text-right" role="navigation">
  <ul class="site-menu main-menu js-clone-nav mr-auto d-none d-lg-block">
    <li><a href="#home-section" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Products
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-text dropdown-header" href="#products-section">All products</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-text" href="idalium-dawn.html">Idalium Dawn</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#agents-section" class="nav-link">Agents</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about-section" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news-section" class="nav-link">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact-section" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

JS code that causes the error

```
var OnePageNavigation = function() {
    var navToggler = $('.site-menu-toggle');
    $("body").on("click", ".main-menu li a[href^='#'], .smoothscroll[href^='#'], .site-mobile-menu .site-nav-wrap li a", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var hash = this.hash;

      $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $(hash).offset().top
      }, 600, 'easeInOutExpo');

        });

        $('.gototop').on('click', function() {


      $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $('body').offset().top
      }, 600, 'easeInOutExpo');
        });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idalium dawn link has no hash because it is external link, so  $(hash).offset() is undefined and this is reason of your error.

For prevent this error you can wrap slider code to condition like that

```
var hash = this.hash;
if(hash) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    'scrollTop': $(hash).offset().top
  }, 600, 'easeInOutExpo');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am having difficulties adjusting it. What do you suggest to change?

Comment: The error message is gone now, but it hasn't changed the behaviour of the site. It still doesn't redirect me to another page.

Comment: Are you sure that you hide e.preventDefault(); inside condition?

Comment: Excuse me I indeed forgot that, now that it is inside the condition it works. Thanks a lot! I just noticed that it does still give the error when the url containts a # after the file, for example: index.html#test, would it be possible to fix this aswell?